# How do I convert UIKit Frame to SceneKit Node position?

Tags: ios, swift, scenekit

I need to Adjust 3D Modal (SceneKit Node) on UIView, I used SceneKit View for load modal it works fine, I am facing issue regarding framing the 3D Modal

Now, issue I faced is The modal I loaded is not at exact position when I wish to load modal

Ex. I write down the Code

`let pointToAdd : CGPoint = self.view.center
self.addSpecModalAt:(position: pointToAdd)`

I don't know how to Convert the SceneKit Position Coordinate from UIKit Position coordinate

Issue : 
[This image is screenshot of current beheviour which is wrong](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4EXjz.png)

I want This :
[This image is screenshot of my requirement](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sX9BE.png)

Comment: You may use ScnView as a bridge between Scene to UIView. or directly use ARKit

Comment: I have already used SCNView, but I need to relate SCN node inside of SCNView  to UIView Frame

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnscenerenderer. Check the section on Working With Projected Scene Contents. You will find all methods you need.

Comment: Thanks for your support, I just reviewed this doc, but It little un-usefull to me, Actually I already loaded Scene in SceneView at Cener of the screen, but My issue is I want to change the position of that SceneView to other position

Comment: what's the point? scene view is a uiview right?